# Javascript value does not change when alternative radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im learning JavaScript....slowly. Im working front end for a friend and learning as I go along. I thought JavaScript would be a better starting point than Jquery so please keep that in mind when answering, unless I am wrong assuming the above.

My problem is as follows

[image]

When looking at above image you can see the estimated return has been correctly calculated for the **low risk** option selected.

However if user clicks **High Risk** radio button *without moving slider and then clicks the get estimate button*. the amount does not update...?

**Only when user moves slider the amount will update according to radio button selected.** But if radio button is changed without moving slider the amount DOES NOT UPDATE. Hope this makes sense? If not please let me know and ill be happy to clarify.

Code as follows:

**Radio Buttons (shortened version)**

```
<input type="radio" id="control_01" name="risk" value="1" checked>
 <input type="radio" id="control_02" name="risk" value="2">
 <input type="radio" id="control_03" name="risk" value="3">
```

**Javascript**

```
 function getReturn() {
   var risk = document.forms[0];
   var slideAmount = document.getElementById("slideAmount").value;
   var txt;
   var returns;
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < risk.length; i++) {
     if (risk[i].checked) {
       txt = risk[i].value;
     } //for
     if (txt = 1) {
       returns = slideAmount * 0.06;
       returns = Math.ceil(returns); // NO decimals
     }
     if (txt = 2) {
       returns = slideAmount * 0.11;
       returns = Math.ceil(returns); // NO decimals

     }
     if (txt = 3) {
       returns = slideAmount * 0.17;
       returns = Math.ceil(returns); // NO decimals

     }
   } //for
   document.getElementById("returns").innerHTML = "ESTIMATED RETURN PA: <span style='color:red'><i class='fa fa-usd fa-lg'></i>" + returns + "</span>";
 }
```

**HTML Button on Click**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lrg" onclick="getReturn()">GET ESTIMATE</button>
        <div id="returns" style="font-weight: 800; color:black; font-size: 15px">Estimated</div>
```

Any advice, help and tips appreciated.

Comment: `txt = 1` is not a comparison, it is an assignment. It has to be `txt == 1`, ... . The way you wrote it `txt = 3`  will always be true, because `3` is truthy.

Comment: @t.niese DOH! And that my friend is the correct answer, and works. Would you like to put it as an answer and il accept?

Comment: @t.niese please provide answers in the answer section. The comments are intended for getting more information about the question.

Comment: @NimrodArgov there are some many duplicates around here on SO that are about the same topic, but because of the nature of this question, they are hard to find. I  think it should be closed as typographical error. But I add it as community wiki answer.

Comment: @t.niese This sort of question isn't a request for information, it's "help me with my code". In these types of questions - while there are probably many with the same issue - pointing someone to another question might just be confusing. Pointing out the error, as you did, is much more efficient.

Comment: @NimrodArgov Q&A here should also help people that have the same problem in future. This kind of questions are borderline to be off topic, and no matter how useful the answers are for the OP, they do not help others in future. `[...] pointing someone to another question might just be confusing[...]` All those dup questions contain nearly the same answers, sometimes even the same wrong advices. But they are already reviewed, or can be reviewed or extended by the one marking as duplicate another time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`txt = 1` is not a comparison, it is an assignment. It has to be `txt == 1`, ... . The way you wrote it `txt = 3`  will always be true, because `3` is truthy.

In general you should use a linter like [eslint](http://eslint.org) or a code styleguide guideline tool like [standardjs](http://standardjs.com), those tools warn you about these common mistakes and pitfalls.

Beside that, you should write this kind of if clauses that way:

```
 if (txt == 1) {
   returns = slideAmount * 0.06;
   returns = Math.ceil(returns); // NO decimals
 } else if (txt == 2) {
   returns = slideAmount * 0.11;
   returns = Math.ceil(returns); // NO decimals
 } else if (txt == 3) {
   returns = slideAmount * 0.17;
   returns = Math.ceil(returns); // NO decimals
 }
```

And if possible use `===` instead of `==`.

```
if (risk[i].checked) {
  txt = Number(risk[i].value); // convert the value to a Number
} //for

if (txt === 1) {
   returns = slideAmount * 0.06;
   returns = Math.ceil(returns); // NO decimals
} else if (txt === 2) {
   returns = slideAmount * 0.11;
   returns = Math.ceil(returns); // NO decimals
} else if (txt === 3) {
   returns = slideAmount * 0.17;
   returns = Math.ceil(returns); // NO decimals
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is just not to correct your mistake, but also to reduce the number of line of code.

```
function getReturn() {
  var risk = document.forms[0];
  var slideAmount = document.getElementById("slideAmount").value;
  var txt;
  var returns;
  for (var i = 0; i < risk.length; i++) {
    if (risk[i].checked) {
      txt = risk[i].value;
    } //for
    if (txt == 1) {
     returns = slideAmount * 0.06;
    } else if (txt == 2) {
     returns = slideAmount * 0.11;
    } else if (txt == 3) {
     returns = slideAmount * 0.17;
    }
  } //for
  document.getElementById("returns").innerHTML = "ESTIMATED RETURN PA: <span style='color:red'><i class='fa fa-usd fa-lg'></i>" + Math.ceil(returns) + "</span>";
}
```

`=` is an assignment operator, whereas `==` is a comparison operator.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code.

1. You should exit your for loop when the radio button has been found
2. As mentioned in several posts, `=` should be replaced with `==` in your comparators.
3. You have incomplete HTML leaving those offering help to make assumptions about your DOM elements.  For example, `<form>` and `<input type="range">` are missing from the example.

Below please find a sample with missing DOM elements added and simplified logic.  A `switch/case` was used as an example because some find this easier to read.  It is otherwise logically equivalent to the `if/else` examples.

```
<html>
<form>
    <input type="radio" id="control_01" name="risk" value="1" checked>
    <input type="radio" id="control_02" name="risk" value="2">
    <input type="radio" id="control_03" name="risk" value="3">
</form>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lrg" onclick="getReturn()">GET ESTIMATE</button>
<div id="returns" style="font-weight: 800; color:black; font-size: 15px">Estimated</div>
<input type="range" id="slideAmount" value="1" max="100"></input>

<script>
function getReturn() {
    var risk = document.forms[0];
    var slideAmount = document.getElementById("slideAmount").value;
    var returns;
    for (var i = 0; i < risk.length; i++) {
        // Skip unchecked radio buttons
        if (!risk[i].checked) {
            continue;
        }
        // Divide by one to force string to value
        switch(risk[i].value/1) {
            case 1:
                returns = Math.ceil(slideAmount * 0.06);
                break;
            case 2:
                returns = Math.ceil(slideAmount * 0.11);
                break;
            case 3:
                returns = Math.ceil(slideAmount * 0.17);
                break;
            default:
                console.error("Shouldn't have reached " + risk[i].value);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("returns").innerHTML = "ESTIMATED RETURN PA: <span style='color:red'><i class='fa fa-usd fa-lg'></i>" + returns + "</span>";
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You should not use constructs like `risk[i].value/1`,  use `parseInt(risk[i].value, 10)`  or `Number(risk[i].value)` instead. The reason why you should not use `/1` is because of maintainability. You always need to add a comment like `// converts string to number`  to indicate that the `/1` is not something that was added by accident. `parseInt` and `Number` does the conversion, and already includes the information that this data has to be converted.

Comment: @t.niese Fair enough however implicit logic happens often in JavaScript and the comments are provided for learning, not for maintainability.  The `/1` can and should be taken as a learning example not necessarily a copy/paste -- much like the change to `switch/case` and the non-mandatory change to a number to begin with, since `switch/case` supports strings as well.

Comment: Yes there are many thing that happen implicitly in js. This is on the one hand a nice thing, but on the other hand could hurt readability or maintainability. If you review a code and see `val/1 === 2` or even worser `+val === 2`, you need to check if this is used to convert a string to a Number, or if it was a `1+val === 2` or similar which was deleted by accident. So you either need to write a comment that makes clear that this is used to convert the string to number or you use those given functions, that make it clear at the fist look that it was intended.

Comment: There are some patterns that work well in certain situations like `options = options || {}`, but they also can be pitfalls if you write `amount = amount || 10`, the `amount || 10` could be a problem because `amount`  can never be `0`,  but could also be intended. So in many situations it is better to be more verbose in the code, because you do not need to explain your code with comments then.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please do these changes in function:

```
 function getReturn() {
   var risk = document.getElementsByName('risk'); // change
   var slideAmount = document.getElementById("slideAmount").value;
   var txt;
   var returns;
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < risk.length; i++) {
     if (risk[i].checked) {
       txt = risk[i].value;
     } //for
     if (txt === "1") {  // change
       returns = slideAmount * 0.06;
       returns = Math.ceil(returns); // NO decimals
     }
     if (txt === "2") { // change
       returns = slideAmount * 0.11;
       returns = Math.ceil(returns); // NO decimals

     }
     if (txt === "3") { // change
       returns = slideAmount * 0.17;
       returns = Math.ceil(returns); // NO decimals

     }
   } //for
   document.getElementById("returns").innerHTML = "ESTIMATED RETURN PA: <span style='color:red'><i class='fa fa-usd fa-lg'></i>" + returns + "</span>";
 }
```